# Comparing string values, infix to postfix

Tags: java, stack, calculator, postfix-notation, infix-notation

```
    Stack<String> s = new Stack<String>();
    String[] tokens = infix.split(" ");

    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();

    Integer.getInteger("+", 1);
    Integer.getInteger("-", 1);
    Integer.getInteger("*", 2);
    Integer.getInteger("/", 2);

    for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++)
    {
        if (tokens[i].matches("[0-9]"))
        {
            output.append(tokens[i] + " ");
        }
        else if (tokens[i].equals("+") || tokens[i].equals("-") || tokens[i].equals("*") || tokens[i].equals("/"))
        {
            if(tokens[i] <= s.peek())
            {

            }
        }
    }

    return output.toString();
```

I'm doing an infix to postfix calculator, and I'm trying to say if the current tokens value is less than or equal to the value of the token at the top of the stack. I used Integer.valueOf to set a numeric value to a specific token, but couldn't use "<=" because they are Strings, do I need to use a String.greaterThan()[fictional] kind of method?

Comment: Uh, `Integer.valueOf("+", 1);` is going to blow up.  "+" isn't a number.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (tokens[i].equals("-") || tokens[i].equals("+") || tokens[i].equals(s.peek))
```

This performs what you are trying to do though it might be less than savory.

I would stick with the if statement and forget about assigning weights, but if you insist the below will work.

Another option is to map each operator to a numeric value, IF you need to give a numeric value to operators:

```
HashMap<String, Integer> operators = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

operators.put("+", 1);
operators.put("-", 1);
operators.put("*", 2);
operators.put("/", 2);
```

Comment: i changed it to getInteger

Comment: i dont know hashmaps yet, wouldn't feel right using that

Comment: @user3427042 I don't think you are approaching this the correct way, if you want to assign weights you a Set or a Map. Though you could just stick to Strings like the above if statement and not have to worry about it.